# Using different style sheet for browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, safari

I just added a video to my site. Looks great on IE & MOZ however it does not play and messes up the site on safari.

My question is how do i ignore the video tags for safari or change the stylesheet?

My Code;

```
<![if !(IE 6)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<![endif]>

<video autoplay loop poster="images/" id="bgvid">
<source src="images/videobgb.mp4" type="video/webm">

</video>
```

I need to ignore the video for safari it does not work.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: you wrote, that your video is in mp4 format, but in the video type you wrote that it is in webm... MP4 is supported in Safari since 3.1 version... You should have videos in multiple formats!

Comment: and in video type you have to write the full line. for example: type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user agent and conditionally add style sheets for white listed browsers.

Here's a link http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml